# Jquery off() for a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table where i have bound all my elements with class="shift" to a click function.

Now, because I also need to use another click event on part of the element, I would like to unbind the click event on element when the mouse enters the element and rebind when i leaves (meant for some touch events and whatnot)

Now, I bind like this

```
$("table").on("touchstart mousedown",".shift", function(e){ ... })
```

But when i try to unbind on a specific element, say it has a class="selected" added to distinguish the current element i use:

```
$("table").off("touchstart mousedown",".shift.selected")
```

which does not work....

I can remove all the handlers at once, but it would be wasteful to remove all the handlers and reinsert them as soon as the mouse leaves.

So, is there a way to remove the handler on a single element after the event is bound to all current and future elements?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you use `$("table").on("touchstart mousedown",".shift:not(.selected)", function(e){ ... })`?

Comment: You can't unbind from `.shift.selected` alone because nothing is actually bound to any `.shift` element. There's only one handler bound, and that's to `table`, and it has an instruction to trigger the handler when the event takes place on `.shift`, so unbinding `.shift.selected` has no impact since you didn't use that selector.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the .selected class is just added when the mouse enters the element. The element is does not have that class when the event is bound 

I did not think it was possible either, but I had to ask, just in case someone had found a way to unbind a single element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to unbind the click event on the element when the mouse enters. I know, the element click event will trigger when you click an inner element with the click event bound, right ? you can stop that:

The click handler of the inner element must look like this:

```
$("some inner element").click(function(event) {
    //That's what are you looking for ;)
    event.stopPropagation();
    //You code here
});
```

`event.stopPropagation()` will prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.